# Supporting sqlite and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an application that needs to support Python 2.4 and 2.6.  With 2.6, sqlite3 replaces sqlite.  Is there much else I need to worry about other than `paramstyle` differences?  Is this a decent way of handling that?

```
try:
    import sqlite3 as sqlite
except ImportError:
    import sqlite

...

if sqlite.paramstyle == 'qmark':
    query = 'SELECT foo FROM bar where baz = ?'
else:
    query = 'SELECT foo FROM bar where baz = %s'
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On python 2.4, use the [`pysqlite` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite). This is the *exact same* package that was added to the Python standard library in version 2.5, when it was renamed to `sqlite3`.

As it is the same package, there are no differences in the API, and you only have to use a `try` `except ImportError` test:

```
try:
    import sqlite3
except ImportError:
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
```

Comment: That certainly makes it a bit simpler to maintain.  Thanks!